# How do I left and right align components in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, alignment

I have what appears to be a simple issue. I have some labels that I'd like to align to the left but when I resize, they start to drift towards the middle. This is going to throw off the alignment of other components I plan on adding. What do I do to keep them to the left?

[image: Example]

It's short, easy code, not sure what my problem is here:

```
package com.protocase.notes.views;

import com.protocase.notes.model.Note;
import com.protocase.notes.model.User;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;

/**
 * @author dah01
 */
public class NotesPanel extends JPanel{

    public NotesPanel(Note note){
        this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JLabel creatorLabel = new JLabel("Note by "+note.getCreator()+ " @ "+note.getDateCreated());
        creatorLabel.setAlignmentX(JLabel.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        creatorLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);


        JTextArea notesContentsArea = new JTextArea(note.getContents());
        notesContentsArea.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(notesContentsArea);

        JLabel editorLabel = new JLabel(" -- Last edited by "+note.getLastEdited() +" at "+note.getDateModified());
        editorLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        editorLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);

        this.add(creatorLabel);
        this.add(scrollPane);
        this.add(editorLabel);
        this.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Notes Panel");
        Note note = new Note();
        User user = new User();
        user.setFirstName("d");
        user.setLastName("h");
        user.setUserID("dah01");
        note.setCreator(user);
        note.setLastEdited(user);
        note.setDateCreated(new Date());
        note.setDateModified(new Date());
        note.setContents("A TEST CONTENTS");
        NotesPanel np = new NotesPanel(note);

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(np);
        frame.setContentPane(scroll);
        np.setVisible(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: But you're explicitly setting the horizontal alignment (i.e. `setAlignmentX`) of each label to the left...what did you think was going to happen?

Comment: Edited: I was just doing that in the example, I've got one changed to right in my code and it does nothing.

Comment: With stub user/note classes: http://pastebin.com/Si0iCPnG

Comment: @dah, Then use the real code...something that truly reflects what you're doing...

Comment: I changed my question to reflect the issue. Code and question line up.

Comment: Start adding other components, then you will come to know, I don't see any issue ...

Comment: It looks like a limitation of `BoxLayout`. Try using [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) instead. You can group top/bottom elements in their own JPanels, as well (with their own layout rules).

Comment: @HarmeetSingh when I resize the window, the labels float into the middle of the panel, I want it neatly bound left.

Comment: @dah a) add some more components and then post your code, this way its not possible to tell what to do. b) You can try `setLayout` `null` and specify `JLabel` bounds, but you should not do this(not recommended).

Comment: @HarmeetSingh regardless of other components, I want these left aligned when maximizing.

Comment: @dah have a look at my answer..

Comment: @dah You were bound to find someone who knew how to use a `BoxLayout` ;)  Why does the majority of StackOverflow assume the solution is changing your layout manager whenever there's a problem? (p.s. I'm guilty of suggesting the same thing on other questions - BoxLayout is just my favorite one, so I find it strange when people suggest to switch it out).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to align things in your panel, you have to align everything.  You forgot to align your `JScrollPane`.  If you add this line to your code, the alignment should be fixed for you:

```
    scrollPane.setAlignmentX(JScrollPane.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
```

And what your new constructor would look like:

```
public NotesPanel(Note note){
    this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    JLabel creatorLabel = new JLabel("Note by "+note.getCreator()+ " @ "+note.getDateCreated());
    creatorLabel.setAlignmentX(JLabel.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    creatorLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);


    JTextArea notesContentsArea = new JTextArea(note.getContents());
    notesContentsArea.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(notesContentsArea);
    scrollPane.setAlignmentX(JScrollPane.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

    JLabel editorLabel = new JLabel(" -- Last edited by "+note.getLastEdited() +" at "+note.getDateModified());
    editorLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    editorLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);

    this.add(creatorLabel);
    this.add(scrollPane);
    this.add(editorLabel);
    this.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
}
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: All I wanted to do was left align it and keep the code simple without having to use nested layout managers.

Answer (score 4):

As per your **comments**, I would recommend you to go with some other `layout`, I would recommend [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/)

Here you go with `MigLayout`:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class MigLayoutDemo {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new MigLayoutDemo();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MigLayoutDemo() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[grow]", "[][grow][]"));

        JLabel lblLabel = new JLabel("Label 1");
            lblLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        contentPane.add(lblLabel, "cell 0 0,alignx left");

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        contentPane.add(textArea, "cell 0 1,grow");

        JLabel lblLabel_1 = new JLabel("Label 2");
            lblLabel_1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        contentPane.add(lblLabel_1, "cell 0 2,alignx left");
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image]

As you can see `labels` marked with **red border** are not stretched to the middle, they are left aligned .

Comment: But, I want them to be left align, running vertically.

Comment: Upvote for the nice answer and example but I really don't want to increase dependencies on outside libraries for something simple like left aligning two labels.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `BorderLayout` definitely fixes your issue.

```
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

this.add(creatorLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
this.add(scrollPane);
this.add(editorLabel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

[image: JLabel alignments]

Alternatively, if you have more components to display in the UI than what you show in the sample code, you can still use a `GridBagLayout`. I know that not many people like to use this one because it's quite verbose but in my opinion, it's the most powerful layout manager of swing.